# Unable to modify width for merged columns using xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

Specifying the width attribute for column 2 is not working, mostly because in the first row, columns 2,3 and 4 are merged.

```
sheet1.col(1).width=256*60
sheet1.col(2).width=256*60
if (j-2)%3 == 0 :  sheet2.write_merge(i,i,j,j+2,woRd,r8)
```

For column 1, width is correctly getting increased as 60, but there is no increase in column 2. Can you please help ?

Comment: Did you ever get an solution to this?